# How to rename index in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

I'm trying to change the index of a row. What I have got so far is:

```
df = pd.read_excel(f)
pd1 = pd.DataFrame(df.iloc[10:21, 1:10])
pd1.columns = df.iloc[6, 1:10]
```

The output is:

```
6  2018-02-16 2018-02-17 2018-02-18 2018-02-19 2018-02-20 2018-02-21  \
10         89         99         89         85         85         89   
11         97         97         88        100        100        100   
12       SOLD        269        209        229        229        229   
...
```

I would like to change the leftmost column (10,11,12) to names located on df.iloc[10:19,0]. The output of which is:

```
10                                       Circle
11                                           BW
12                                      Delamar
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: `df.index = df.iloc[10:21,0]`  ?

Comment: You might want to set the row and column indexes in the call to `read_excel` -- i.e.,  `df = pd.read_excel(f, index_col=[0], header=[6])`.